# split the string with pattern python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have one string like following, how can I use re to split the string into I use re.find and sub that works but just take couple step any better

```
k = '12345567 I love this 1234 - One'
x = re.findall(r'^\d+ ', k)[0]
y = re.sub(x, '', k)
res = [x[:-1], y] # ['12345567', 'I love this 1234 - One']
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can solve this by using the split function:

```
k = '12345567 I love this 1234 - One'.split(' ',1)
# ['12345567', 'I love this 1234 - One']
```